# Dynamic Activity Definition (Design Automation)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am reaching out with the question, since I was not able to find an answer in the documentation.

I am working on an app, where the input arguments for Design Automation may vary, and are reliant entirely on the user. Thus I have been wondering what is the most optimal way to approach this subject.

Currently, every time before creating the WorkItem, hence executing the Design Automation script I ensure that prior activity of the same name had been deleted, and create a new one with correct number of input arguments. But the process seems to be suboptimal. Here's body of my activity definition for the reference:

```
{
    "commandLine": [activity_commandLine],
    "parameters": {
        "HostDwg": {
            "zip": false,
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "Host drawing",
            "localName": "$(HostDwg)"
        },
        "blockDwg0": {
            "zip": false,
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "Dwg to add to host dwg"
        },  
        "blockDwg1": {
            "zip": false,
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "Dwg to add to host dwg"
        }, 
...
```

The code I have implemented now works well, but I've been wondering whether perhaps I could somehow pass an array of additional arguments, hence I would not have to delete the activity and re-define it every time the Design Automation needs to be run.

Note: I cannot zip the files and pass them as a package, since the files are stored in the OSS.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: yes, Design Automation can support the passing of an array of arguments in WorkItem. 
We will work on the blog and APS doc(https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/) for this feature. We will keep you posted

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quickly! That would be really cool to have a blog post about it!

Comment: If you have arguments that vary dynamically, you can have one argument, that takes a JSON as parameter from the workitem, you can download or upload the files or variable values by reading the json from your app plugin...  Design Automation for AutoCAD has now open network access by default.

Comment: Those dynamic arguments are drawing files stored in the APS OSS. So what you suggest is to pass a JSON file to the app plugin with signed urls of the files and let the app plugin download them?

Comment: That's correct., since you own OSS, you can actually just pass the objectId of objects in the buckets, you can download the files using Forge .NET SDK. 
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-design-automation-dotnet/blob/a925f7e66d1de97203de14841dfeb5e32f89639b/designAutomationSample/Controllers/DesignAutomationController.cs#L419